# find distinct Data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to find the all viewed experiences from collections its working but there are duplicate entries i need to use **distinct** by **expId** i don't know how to use distinct here. please help i am new here.

```
function getViewedExperiences(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        Views.find({userId: req.userId},function(err,result){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }else{
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

my result is -

```
{
"msg": "Recently Viewed Experiences",
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "5aab6ad75ed3dc24ac5c492c",
        "userId": "5aaa662357421667e989a286",
        "expId": "5aab533972beff1c9880eb86",
        "__v": 0,
        "created": "2018-03-16T06:57:27.694Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5aab6b475ed3dc24ac5c492d",
        "userId": "5aaa662357421667e989a286",
        "expId": "5aab52e272beff1c9880eb85",
        "__v": 0,
        "created": "2018-03-16T06:59:19.975Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5aab6bc75ed3dc24ac5c492e",
        "userId": "5aaa662357421667e989a286",
        "expId": "5aab52e272beff1c9880eb85",
        "__v": 0,
        "created": "2018-03-16T07:01:27.973Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

here how i use distinct??

Comment: @SaikatHajra but how do i use my query here?

Comment: `$group` by `expId` can be helpful for you @Devendra

Comment: @SaikatHajra thank you for your response. so i don't need to use distinct $group will work for me?

Comment: yes use `$group` operator, hope you will get the desired output.

Comment: @Devendrachauhan further explaining @Saikat comment, you can use aggregate to get distinctly with all data like this   `db.<table>.aggregate([ {$match:{userId:"<userId to search>"}},{$group:{ _id:"$expId",userId:{$first:"$userId"},docId:{$first:"$_id"} }}, {$project: {docId:1,userId:1,expId:1}} ])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getViewedExperiences(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        Views.distinct('expId', {userId: req.userId},function(err,result){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }else{
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: i tried but it gives me only __expId__ i need all data.